# Auto Photo Crop

Tags: imagemagick, image-processing

I want to crop photo black background with command line

This command didn't help:

```
convert input.png -trim output.png
```

[My image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nqtg.jpg)

Comment: Possibly related to http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4949/what-is-the-best-way-to-auto-crop-bulk-images

Comment: I need to do it on comman line

Answer (score 2):

You could try Imagemagick's `-trim` option with `-fuzz`:

> The `-trim` option removes any edges that are exactly the same color as the corner pixels. Use `-fuzz` to make `-trim` remove edges that are nearly the same color as the corner pixels.

For example:

```
convert input.png -trim -fuzz 10% output.png
```

You can adjust the `-fuzz` value up or down until it is cropping the amount that you want. Here is information about the `-fuzz` value:

> `-fuzz distance{%}`
>
> Colors within this distance are considered equal.
>
> A number of algorithms search for a target color. By default the color must be exact. Use this option to match colors that are close to the target color in RGB space. For example, if you want to automagically trim the edges of an image with -trim but the image was scanned and the target background color may differ by a small amount. This option can account for these differences.
>
> The distance can be in absolute intensity units or, by appending % as a percentage of the maximum possible intensity (255, 65535, or 4294967295).
>
> Use +fuzz to reset the fuzz value to 0.

Please let me know if this answer was helpful, or if you have other questions or need clarification.

Comment: convert: invalid argument for option `-fuzz': output.png @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1631. I get this error

Comment: I apologize -- I gave you incorrect and incomplete information. `-fuzz` requires a number or a percentage. I have updated my answer to correct the error and give more information about the usage of `-fuzz`.

Comment: Now I tested trim and fuzz functions with my photo then I crop receipt and  filled some black color with image editor,so its working okey,but then I just take photo on black paper backround no. I`m not good at english,but I need to know that black paper backround color code or what?